# How to add a folder library to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I'm trying to add this [library](https://github.com/savvasdalkitsis/JTMDB).
Then I made a folder called lib at the same level as my src folder, then right click import as file structure to the lib folder.

Then went to `Project->Properties->Build Path->Libraries`.

Then do I add class folder? If so does it matter what folder I pick because there are 4 or 5 nested folders.

Then do I import `com.savvasdalkitsis.jtmb.*;`? Or at what point from the folder path do I import?

Comment: Can you compile it to a jar and add the jar reference to your build path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then do I import com.savvasdalkitsis.jtmb.*;? Or at what point from the folder path do I import?

To be able to import `com.savvasdalkitsis.jtmb.*`, the com folder in `src/main/java` folder in that library should be in your class path, i.e. copy the java folder under `src/main` in that library as is into your project and right click on `java` and select the `Add to build path` menu option. Then com.* will be in your class path and can be referred to using the import you specified.

Comment: ok so when I copy java into my project folder i now have java.com.sav.... in the project folder but when I right click on it there is no add to build path. There is build path (use as source folder, exclude, and configure build path) If I choose configure build path and try an add the folder it says "cant nest 'the path'.